# How to call an internal R C function from your own code

Tags: r

I'd like to reuse R code from the `stats` package that simulates contingency tables to compute a simulated `p.value` for a chi-squared test.

When looking at the `chisq.test` function source code, you can see the following :

```
 if (simulate.p.value && all(sr > 0) && all(sc > 0)) {
        setMETH()
        tmp <- .Call(C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E)
        STATISTIC <- sum(sort((x - E)^2/E, decreasing = TRUE))
        PARAMETER <- NA
        PVAL <- (1 + sum(tmp >= almost.1 * STATISTIC))/(B + 
            1)
    }
```

The interesting line here is the `.Call` call :

```
tmp <- .Call(C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E)
```

What I'd like to do, if it is possible, is to use this `C_chisq_sim` function in my own code, but I can't manage to do it. If I try with :

```
tmp <- .Call(C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E, PACKAGE="stats")
```

I get a `C_chisq_sim object not found` error. And if I try with :

```
tmp <- .Call("C_chisq_sim", sr,sc,B,E, PACKAGE="stats")
```

I get an error saying that the entry point is not in the loading table.

I'd like a solution that would be cross-platform, if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick I guess:

```
tmp <- .Call(stats:::C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E, PACKAGE="stats")
```

Comment: How is this possible without resorting to `:::` (and thereby avoiding the wrath of CRAN)?

Comment: This helped me create a `g.test` for the popular, new-ish *G*-test; a replacement for the Chi^2-test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have is to use the R function `r2dtable` (see [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/r2dtable.html)).

Both `C_chisq_sim` and `r2dtable` utilize the same **AS159 algorithm**. If you'd like other source code options, see this [reference](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/asa159/asa159.html).